C# MongoDB Referencing a document instead of including it
I'd like to save these classes in two separate collections, with the Categories property containing just a link to the corresponding entry in the category collection.
public class Phonebook
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}


I've previously used LiteDb where I could do this to tell LiteDb that the Categories is a reference.
BsonMapper.Global.Entity<PhoneBook>()
    .DbRef(x => x.Categories, GetCollectionName<Category>());

and then access it using
database.GetCollection<Phonebook>()
    .Include(x => x.Categories).FindOne(x => x.Id == myId);

(without the Include it would just return the Id prop of the Categories)
How does that translate to MongoDb and the C# driver?
I know from the sample data model you'd probably ask 'why not include the in the Phonebook document?', but the categories are used elsewhere and need to be managed separately (and the same categories need to be available throughout the system).

.net driver can't do it, you should do it manually

so is the documentation incorrect? Cos it states that it's supported in the C# driver. Even as far back as MongoDB 3, the doc lists the C# driver as having support for DbRefs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/

DBRef is supported, but all steps you should do manually. I touched DBRef long time ago, but as I recall, the only logic you can have with this is just a pointer on a document. I don't think driver can do anything fancy with this
